# запрет выбора Select`a по условию

Tags: javascript

Нужно заблокировать выбор города из списка, пока не выбрана область. Как это можно на js реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пишите <select disabled>...</select> потом в js меняете item.disabled=false;

Answer (score 2):

Используйте свойство .disabled и устанавливайте ему значение true или false.

```js
var cityUndisable = function() {
  document.getElementById('city').disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<select id="region" onchange="cityUndisable()">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Выбери регион</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="city" disabled="true">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Выбери город</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```